# Wikipedia api search for text sort by relevancy

Tags: wikipedia-api

When I search in wiki **UI** for `stack overflow` I get different results from the API.
In the UI:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Stack+Overflow&title=Special%3ASearch&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&ns0=1

In the API:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&origin=*&generator=search&prop=extracts&gsrsearch=Stack%20Overflow&gsrlimit=20&exintro=1&explaintext=1&exchars=350&exlimit=20

The thing that I'm missing in the API is sort by relevancy.
How can that be achieved?

Comment: The API result in fact contains the relevancy ranking. It is hidden in the `index` property of each page. For example, the first result in the UI "Stack Overflow" has `"index": 1,`.

Comment: @user15517071 Great! thank you. if you want to get rewarded, post an answer and ill accept it. BTW, do you know if its possible to run multiple searches in a single request? thanks

Comment: Glad I helped :). As for running multiple searches, I'll have to look into that since I can't think of a way off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API result in fact contains the relevancy ranking. It is hidden in the `index` property of each page. For example, the first result in the UI "Stack Overflow" has `"index": 1,`.

(Curiously, the pages are ordered correctly when `search` is used as a list, not a generator)